# Содержит ли словарь хотя бы одно слово из строки/списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка или список: `'i like girls'`   или   `['i', 'like', 'girls']`
И словарь со словами `{'i': None, 'like': None, 'birds': None}`
Есть ли быстрый способ проверить, есть ли хотя бы одно слово из строки/списка в этом словаре? В идеале за О(1)

Comment: есть - используйте пересечение множеств

Comment: За константу нельзя. За время пропорциональное длине строки можно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно решить вот так.

```
my_list = ['i', 'like', 'girls']
my_dir = {'i': None, 'like': None, 'birds': None}

s1 = set(my_list)  # Множество различных слов в списке
s2 = set(my_dir.keys())  # Берем множество ключей словаря
if len(s1 & s1) > 0:  # Если размер пересечения больше 0 - то такое слово есть
    print('есть такое слово')
else:
    print('нет такого слова')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of = ['i', 'like', 'girls']
dict_of = {'i': None, 'like': None, 'birds': None}
```

**Вариант 1:**

```
set(list_of) & set(dict_of)
>>> {'like', 'i'}
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
[i for i in list_of for j in dict_of if i == j]
>>> ['i', 'like']
```

Comment: и все-таки ответ отвечает не совсем на поставленный вопрос.